# c++ win32 program has caused the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way

Tags: c++, winapi

i have written a program to take a screenshot and show it. Most of the code has been copied from Stack Overflow answers:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace cv;
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define VC_EXTRALEAN
using namespace std;
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    HDC hwindowDC,hwindowCompatibleDC;

    int height,width,srcheight,srcwidth;
    HBITMAP hbwindow;
    Mat src;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;

    hwindowDC=GetDC(NULL);
    hwindowCompatibleDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
    SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC,COLORONCOLOR);  

    RECT windowsize;
    GetClientRect(NULL, &windowsize);

    srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
    srcwidth = windowsize.right;
    height = windowsize.bottom/2;
    width = windowsize.right/2;

    src.create(height,width,CV_8UC4);

    // create a bitmap
    hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hwindowDC, width, height);
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = width;    
    bi.biHeight = -height;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;    
    bi.biBitCount = 32;    
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;  
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;    
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
    StretchBlt( hwindowCompatibleDC, 0,0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0,srcwidth,srcheight, SRCCOPY);
    GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC,hbwindow,0,height,src.data,(BITMAPINFO *)&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    DeleteObject (hbwindow); DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC); ReleaseDC(NULL, hwindowDC);
    imshow("im",src);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with:

```
g++ -o sc sc.cpp -mwindows -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/opencv4/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc
```

After compiling successfully, on running sc.exe it shows the following error window
[image: error window]

can anyone tell me why this is happening? Also please do suggest other corrections in the code if anything is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Build with debug information (add the `-g` flag when building) and run in a debugger. If the debugger catches it, look where in your code it happens. If not, then step through the code statement by statement until it happens.

Comment: There are many opportunities in this code for error checking but there is none. You might consider that.

Comment: i am running in a debugger. It just shows "task completed successfully"

Comment: @Some programmer dude i ran the code line by line by giving breakpoints and i found out that it shows that error after i jump over the line `imshow("im", src)` (line 540 of basic_string.h)

Comment: Set up your debugger to break when a C++/SEH exception is thrown. Once you hit the debugger, you both see where the exception gets raised, as well as the call stack that shows you how you got there.

Comment: @IInspectable yes i set up a catchpoint at exception std::runtime_error and it gets raised at the line `imshow("im", src)`